# How to fix unable to locate Android SDK without using Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, sdk

i have installed flutter sdk but when in command flutter doctor its showing unable to locate Android sdk and i need to download android studio but i dont want to use Android studio i only want to use vs code can i use Android sdk in vs code

i want to use flutter using vs code without Android studio and its not running because its showing unable to locate Android sdk

Comment: Please share the platform (OS) you're using (Win/Mac/Linux), also share the screenshot/copy the error log to evaluate

Comment: 10 seconds of googling gave me this which might help you. https://guides.codepath.com/android/installing-android-sdk-tools#:~:text=%2F-,Installing%20the%20Android%20SDK%20(Manual%20Way),for%20your%20build%20machine%20OS. It's a lot easier to simply install Android Studio to get the sdk ... and then choose not to use AS